# How to solve NoSuchElementException in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, program-entry-point

The error is:

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException    at
> java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)   at
> java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)      at
> java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)   at
> java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)   at
> project4.Project4.main(Project4.java:16)
```

Here is the getInput method I used:

```
public class IO {

    public static Scanner getInput(String prompt){
        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
        return new Scanner(s);
    }


public class Project4 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan =IO.getInput("Enter an integers: ");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        int y = scan.nextInt();
        if (x>0 && y>0){
            IO.showMessage(String.format("sum: %4d", x+y), "REsults:");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read like this:

```
int x;
int y;

if (scan.hasNext()) {
    x = scan.nextInt();
}

if (scan.hasNext() {
    y = scan.nextInt();
}
```

May be your program is not getting input.